# Do-While won't repeat itself

Tags: c#

I need the user to enter their age, then the program has to calculate how much money they are going to have when their age hit pension. The person is saving 500 or 1000 depending on the situation.

My code won't repeat the if and else statement even though I wrote a Do-While loop. Am I supposed to use a bool-statement? How or where? Or there something else I need to look at?

I've tried using only 'while' but I think I need to use a do-while.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.Write("Enter age");
    string str = Console.ReadLine();
    int MyAge = Convert.ToInt32(str);
    int money = 15000;
    {
        do
        {
            {
                if (money > 20000 || MyAge < 60)
                {
                    Console.Write("You are saving little");
                    money = money + 500;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write("You are saving a lot");
                    money = money + 1000;
                }
                MyAge++;
            }
        }
        while (money > 20000 && MyAge > 65);
    }

    Console.Write("You are retired by the age of " + MyAge + " and you saved " + money + " dollars.");
}
```

I expected the program to hit at least 65 but it ends by the age of 26 of I type down that I'm 25 years old. So it doesn't loop.

Comment: `while (money > 20000 && MyAge > 65)` -- that means the loop continues if `money` is larger than `20000` and the age is larger than `65`. I don't get the `money` part but for the `age` I guess you want the opposite like `age <=  65`. The other comparisons look like they should probably switched too.

Comment: This is called a bug.  You will write many of them, so now is a good time to learn to use the debugger: **[Navigating through Code using the Step Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx)**

Comment: Hmm it doesn't seem to work when I changed it to age<=65. But thanks for your comment! The result was the same: 

Enter age: 25
You are saving little
You are retired by the age of 26 and you saved 15500 dollars.

I will check of the debugger!

Comment: you need to do your function while money is less than 20000, not more than.

Comment: Could you remove those unnecessary braces? They shouldn't change the outcome at all but it's confusing and unnecessary.

Comment: @ecg8 Isn't it what I did? Doesn't the following statement mean that while money is more than 20000 and age is higher than 65, it should repeat itself?

while (money > 20000 && MyAge > 65)

Answer (score 0):

your while loop runs while the age is above 65.

should be `while (money > 20000 && MyAge < 65);`

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but when I made the change I still get the same answer. """Enter age25
You are saving littleYou are retired by the age of 26 and you saved 15500 dollars."""

Comment: Run your code on linqPad with starting age of 25 i reaches 65 for me.

Answer (score 0):

This Works fine:

> I removed `money > 20000` because this condition will never be fulfilled by current flow

```
 public static void Main()
        {
            int MyAge = 25;
            int money = 15000;
            do
            {
                if (money > 20000 || MyAge < 60)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You are saving little");
                    money = money + 500;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You are saving a lot");
                    money = money + 1000;
                }
                MyAge++;
            }
            while (MyAge < 65);
            Console.Write("You are retired by the age of " + MyAge + " and you saved " + money + " dollars.");
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for you comment, although the user needs to be able to input his own age... Although something needs to be changed with:

 while (MyAge < 65 && money > 20000) 

Since the question is, when can the user go in pension after earning more than 20000. The user could actually be 64 starting out with 15000.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hit it more times, when you say that you are 25 years old, you need to change conditions in your while statement.  It should look something like this under.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter age");
            string str = Console.ReadLine();
            int MyAge = Convert.ToInt32(str);
            int money = 15000;
            {
                do
                {
                    {
                        if (money > 20000 || MyAge < 60)
                        {
                            Console.Write("You are saving little");
                            money = money + 500;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.Write("You are saving a lot");
                            money = money + 1000;
                        }
                        MyAge++;
                    }
                }
                while (money < 40000 && MyAge < 65);
            }

            Console.Write("You are retired by the age of " + MyAge + " and you saved " + money + " dollars.");
    }
```

PS "money > 20000" is just to small number and you reach it very fast.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to type || instead of && in the while code! Thanks everybody for your help! Couldn't have done this without you. :)

```
                while ((MyAge < 65) || (money < 20000));
```